# iOS Stacks or equivalent functionality

Tags: ios, jailbreak, dock, launchbar

Fairly simple question, is there a way, either through existing functionality or by jail breaking that you can add Stacks to the iOS dock.

EDIT:
There are three different formats in the way that Stacks work on OSX, Grid (iOS Folder View), Fan and List.

Is there any implementation of Fan or List views?

Comment: If you mean stacks of apps aka Folders. Yes it's possible.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: While this answers the question, strictly speaking, it isn't useful. Please elaborate: how can this be done? Does it require jailbreaking? etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Long press any app icon to enter "wiggle mode".
2. Drag the desired folder to the Dock.
3. Press the Home button to exit "wiggle mode".

Done!

Comment: Though it sounds like maybe it's more difficult to do this on an iPhone/iPod touch if that's what you're using. this works on an iPad, but I don't see why you wouldn't have found it out already by now if so.

Comment: given you an upvote for showing the Grid view in iOS but that's not the full Stacks experience.

Comment: @StuWilson Thank you; I somewhat misunderstood and thought you meant "how to put folders on the Dock." Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Not through folders, no, but if you're JailBroken, there're a couple tweaks in Cydia that you can get called Infinidock and Cascade. They're $1.99 and $0.99, respectively. When you put them together, it adds an Overflow type of look to your dock. It's close to what you're asking, but other than that, there isn't anything that does what you want.